# Entity Framework Core Saving Disconnected Entities and handling Delete on related data automatically?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I would love to have the "Cascade Delete" behavior to happens in an Update scenario for related data.

This is the case where I have an entity coming from a disconnected model and I want to update the database with every related entities. It is documented on MSDN on this page (section Handling deletes):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities

Let's say I have a few one-to-one and one-to-many relationships:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("Entity");
    entity.HasKey(t => t.Id);
    entity.HasMany(e => e.Module)
        .WithOne().HasForeignKey("Device_FK").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    entity.HasOne(e => e.CommunicationSetting)
        .WithOne().HasForeignKey<CommunicationSetting>("Device_FK").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
});
```

Now I want to update this "Entity" with a new one coming from a disconnected scenario:

```
public void SaveEntity(Entity newEntity)
{
    using (var context = new EntityDataContext())
    {
        context.MyEntities.Update(newEntity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

With this code, if I pass a "newEntity" containing a Module/CommunicationSetting with an existing ID, it will update the module properties correctly. If I pass a new Module/CommunicationSetting with an ID of 0, it will be created correctly. But in the case where I pass an empty list or a list with one less Module, or null as the CommunicationSetting, it WON'T delete them. This is documented in the link above.

Now, my question is can this can be flagged to be done automatically?

The solution proposed on MSDN requires to first load the entity with a query, and then loop over all related entities and compare the IDs to see if it's missing in the new entity to save and call "Remove()" on them. This is extremely inefficient and require massive amount of custom code when you have a complex data model containing multiple levels of related data. My "SaveEntity" function would get extremely complex.

What is strange, is that with the "Cascade Delete" rule, deleting the base entity correctly loop through all related data and also delete them correctly, why doesn't Update behave the same?

I would love to have some generic method to do this. Maybe convention-based? Or maybe defined at the property level on the FluentAPI modelBuilder rules? Or a method that would automatically parse the defined relations and recursively loop on all related data automatically and call Remove() if the ID is missing in the new entity without having to manually go through every one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More discussion on [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17626) thread on github.

I managed to come up with a workaround solution. Code is not the cleanest and feel a bit novice, but it works for me. I requires all entities to have an "Id" property.

First create an interface:

```
public interface IDatabaseEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
    List<KeyValuePair<IDatabaseEntity, IDatabaseEntity>> GetOneRelations(IDatabaseEntity newVal);
    List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> GetManyRelations(IDatabaseEntity newVal);
}
```

Then have all your entity class implementing it and defines relations that are "owned" and needs to be updated:

```
public class Entity : IDatabaseEntity
{
    // More stuff here... 

    #region IDatabaseEntity
    public List<KeyValuePair<IDatabaseEntity, IDatabaseEntity>> GetOneRelations(IDatabaseEntity newVal)
    {
        var ret = new List<KeyValuePair<IDatabaseEntity, IDatabaseEntity>>();

        if (newVal is Entity newEntity)
        {
            ret.Add(new KeyValuePair<IDatabaseEntity, IDatabaseEntity>(CommunicationSetting, newEntity.CommunicationSetting));
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> GetManyRelations(IDatabaseEntity newVal)
    {
        var ret = new List<KeyValuePair<object, object>>();

        if (newVal is Entity newEntity)
        {
            ret.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>(Module, newEntity.Module));
        }

        return ret;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And finally on the repository save operation instead of calling DbContext.Update:

```
    public T SaveRow<T>(DbContext context, DbSet<T> table, T original, T toSave, out string changeSet) where T : class, IDatabaseEntity
    {
        Validation.ValidateNotNull(toSave, "rowToSave");

        SaveEntity(context, original, toSave);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return toSave;
    }

    private void SaveEntity<T>(DbContext context, T original, T toSave) where T : class, IDatabaseEntity
    {
        if (original == null)
        {
            if (toSave != null)
                context.Add(toSave);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(toSave);
            foreach (var oneRelation in original.GetOneRelations(toSave))
                UpdateOneRelation(context, oneRelation.Key, oneRelation.Value);

            foreach (var manyRelation in original.GetManyRelations(toSave))
                UpdateManyRelation(context, manyRelation.Key, manyRelation.Value);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateOneRelation(DbContext context, IDatabaseEntity original, IDatabaseEntity toSave)
    {
        if (original != null && toSave == null)
            context.Remove(original);
        else
            SaveEntity(context, original, toSave);
    }

    private void UpdateManyRelation(DbContext context, object originalCol, object toSaveCol)
    {
        var original = originalCol as IList;
        var toSave = toSaveCol as IList;

        if (original == null) return;
        if (toSave != null)
        {
            foreach (var newEntity in toSave.OfType<IDatabaseEntity>())
            {
                var existingEntity = original.OfType<IDatabaseEntity>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == newEntity.Id);

                if (existingEntity == null)
                {
                    original.Add(newEntity);
                }
                else
                {
                    SaveEntity(context, existingEntity, newEntity);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var existingEntity in original.OfType<IDatabaseEntity>())
        {
            if (toSave == null || toSave.OfType<IDatabaseEntity>().All(t => t.Id != existingEntity.Id))
            {
                context.Remove(existingEntity);
            }
        }
    }
```